# Detecting CSS property value of a html element by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, properties

Untill the alert it is ok, But the if is not executing. Here the program stack. Is there any way to detect the display property of div that is it "bloc" or "none"?

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
   alert("Hamdun Soft Past Job Will be Deleted");
   if(document.getElementById(i).style.display=="block")
   document.getElementById(i).innerHTML="Hamdun Soft Is Clear Now";           
 }
```

Oh! Kepp in mind that from div with id=1 to 10, one's display= "block" and all of the 9 is "none". I did that with another JavaScript program. But now I need to detect the "block" one. Tanks.

Comment: I´m not sure, problem could be here with using numeric IDs - id value should begin with non-numeric character.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, always try to provide a Fiddle. That usually is always more helpful. It also tells us, your other dependencies :)

Comment: @panther thanks. But if I delete if and replace i by 1 then the div with id 1 is changed with the innerhtml.

Comment: @LearningNeverStops thanks, I will try next time in sha Allah.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman: Divs will have `id=i1`, `id=i2`, ..., in JS you will have on lines 4 and 5 `getElementById('i' + i)`. But I=m not sure if it= s the problem.

Comment: thanks, but with numerical it is also working @panther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `Element.style.display` will only work when the element has an inline style. You need to get the computed style:

```js
for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
    var elem = document.getElementById(i);

    if((elem.currentStyle ? elem.currentStyle.display : getComputedStyle(elem, null).display) == 'block')
    elem.innerHTML="Hamdun Soft Is Clear Now"; 
}
```

```html
<div id="1">aaa</div>
<div id="2">aaa</div>
<div id="3">aaa</div>
<div id="4">aaa</div>
<div id="5">aaa</div>
<div id="6">aaa</div>
<div id="7">aaa</div>
<div id="8">aaa</div>
<div id="9">aaa</div>
<div id="10">aaa</div>
```

Note: `elem.currentStyle` is first checked because IE can use this .

Answer (score 1):

Like Zigmantas said, the problem is with the id. In HTML4 an id needs to start with a letter. Even though numeric ID's are allowed in HTML5, other problems may arise.

Note that the style needs to be explicitly set on the element. In this example, the third div DOES have the style, but not inline, so it is not selected. The first one is, like you requested.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    div:last-child <!-- #3 does not work in chrome -->
    {
      display:block;   color:red
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
    <div id="1" style="display:block;color:red">one</div>
    <div id="2" >two</div>
    <div id="3" >three</div>
    </section>
    </body>

    <script>
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++)
      {
       alert("Hamdun Soft Past Job Will be Deleted");
       // getComputedStyle would probably be better.
       // as would using an id starting with a letter.
       if(document.getElementById(''+i).style.display=="block")
       document.getElementById(''+i).innerHTML="Hamdun Soft Is Clear Now";           
     }
     </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. got solution with getComputedStyle.

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.getElementById(i).style.display==""`, since "display" doesn't specify at initial, it set default as "".

```js
function Display()
{
for(i=1;i<=6;i++)
  {
   if(document.getElementById(i).style.display=="block" ||     document.getElementById(i).style.display=="")
   document.getElementById(i).innerHTML="Hamdun Soft Is Clear Now";           
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="1" style="display:none;">111</div>
<div id="2" style="display:block;">222</div>
<div id="3">333</div>
<div id="4" style="display:inline;">444</div>
<div id="5" style="display:list-item;">555</div>
<div id="6" style="display:initial;">666</div>

<input type="button" onclick="Display()" value="Press">
```

Comment: thanks, It is working here but can't understand why not in my localserver.

Comment: @MuhammadAshikuzzaman Do you try to alert(document.getElementById(1).style.display); yet?

Comment: The problem is when i<10 it is like 01,02,03 but it should be 1,2,3. Now i had got the solution with getComputedStyle . But document.getElementById(i).style.display=="block" is not working. thanks.